# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'guildes' of undefined Discord.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

can you please help me
i just need to change the bot status every 10 secs
here's the code

```
const mySecret = process.env['token']

const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log(`Discord.js: Ready on: ${client.user.tag} ✅`)
 
 const activitives = [
   `${this.client.guildes.cache.size} servers!`,
   `${this.client.channels.cache.size} channels!`,
   `${this.client.guildes.cache.reduce((a,b) => a + b.memberCount, 0)} users!`,
 ];
 
  let i = 0

  setInterval(() => this.client.user.serActivity(`?bhelp |${activities[i++ % activities.length]}`, { type : 'LISTENING'}), 20);
})
```

Comment: [What's the problem?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 2):

Okay so firstly, its `guild` not `guildes` also, you have to remove the `.this` function
Lemme try and redefine the code so you achieve what you want

```
const Discord = require('discord.js')
const client = new Discord.Client();
client.on('ready', () => {
 console.log(`Discord.js: Ready on: ${client.user.tag} ✅`)
 
 const activities= [
   `${client.guilds.cache.size} servers!`,
   `${client.channels.cache.size} channels!`,
   `${client.users.cache.size} users!`,
 ];
setInterval(() => {
        const index = Math.floor(Math.random() * (activities.length - 1) + 1);
        client.user.setActivity(`?bhelp | ${activities[index]});
    }, 10000);
```

This should pretty much be it your logic and code was almost perfect, just a few typos and misused functions that I fixed.

Comment: it did not work

Comment: send your code, you might've done something wrong